How to choose the correct range when scaling data
I have a model that rates the complexity levels of passages,  and the results i got for each passage range from 1-15. then I asked humans to rate the complexity level on a 3-point scale 1,2 and 3 where a higher score indicate a higher complexity, and I got human ratings ranging from 1-2. If I want to scale the results of my model into a comparable scale of human ratings, should I choose a range of 1-3 (oeiginal scale given to participant) or 1-2 (actual ratings of participant)?
I've tried doing both, but when I scaled to a range of 1-3, the results were a bit different than those given by the model.
